# Error while passing value in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom, parameters, parameter-passing

```
  var d = ""; 
            var c = ""; 
            var table = "<div id='h' style='overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:60vh'>";
            db.collection("Notes")
            .where("user","==",current_email)
            .get().then((snapshot)=>{
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc=>{
                    count++;

                d = doc.data()["title"];
                c = doc.data()["content"];
          if(count != 0){

              table += "<b><label id='titleb'>"+d.toUpperCase()+"</label></b><br><label id='titleba'>"+c+"</label><b><img id='del' src='del.svg' onclick='delme('"+d+"')'><br><br><br>";  
            }
          else{
              table += "<label>You dont have any notes</label>";
          }
```

I am trying to pass a value to a js function on click on an image but I am getting error as the unexpected end of input. Can anyone tell me how to pass a parameter to this function.i am writing this HTML content dynamically and need to pass the value

```
function delme(dd){
    console.log(dd);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `onclick='delme(\""+d+"\")'`

```js
 table="";
 count=1;
 d="da"
 c=1
 if(count != 0){

              table += "<b><label id='titleb'>"+d.toUpperCase()+"</label></b><br><label id='titleba'>"+c+"</label><b><img id='del' src='del.svg' onclick='delme(\""+d+"\")'><br><br><br>";  
            }
          else{
              table += "<label>You dont have any notes</label>";
          }

$("#test").html(table)
function delme(dd){
    console.log(dd);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') everywhere when defining HTML attributes.